# Two legged OAuth using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I have read up on two legged OAuth and understand the principals behind it - my question is specific to the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/) library.  Is there sample code or supporting documentation on how to use DotNetOpenAuth via two legged authentication?  Three legged appears to be supported quite well and since two legged is simply a reduction in the number of steps I would assume this would be easy - so far, this isn't the case.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no samples of 2-legged OAuth with DotNetOpenAuth.  If you're running into issues with doing it by just removing one leg from the existing samples, please describe the issues here: http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/83 so they can be fixed.